# Having problem in changing container color of status while passing props from dummy data

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm having issue on how to **change color of the status container** while passing props from **dummy data**. I'm able to **change font color** of **the status** but not the container color **same as the font color**. Please do help me out. Below i have attached the picture of UI and the code. I used this method to change the color for the font of the status:

```
<Text style={[GlobalStyle.ReceiptAccept, migrateData.status === "Declined" && GlobalStyle.ReceiptDeclined,  migrateData.status === "Pending" && GlobalStyle.ReceiptPending]}>{migrateData.status}</Text>
```

**UI Picture:**

[image]

**PendingReceipt.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image, FlatList,ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import GlobalStyle from '../components/GlobalStyle';
import { HeaderBar2 } from '../components/HeaderBar';
import {GrayCustomView} from './../components/styles';

const ReceiptDetailsScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {
    const {migrateData} = route.params;
    return (
    <ScrollView  style={[GlobalStyle.GrayScrollView]}>
        <HeaderBar2/>
        <View style={[GlobalStyle.AlignReceiptDetailContainer]}>
            <View style={[GlobalStyle.ReceiptDetailContainer]}>
                <View style={[GlobalStyle.AlignReceiptHeaderContainer]}>
                    <View style={[GlobalStyle.ReceiptHeader1]}>
                        <Text style={[GlobalStyle.ReceiptListTitle]}>{migrateData.receiptnum}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={[GlobalStyle.ReceiptPendingContainer]}>
                        <Text style={[GlobalStyle.ReceiptAccept, migrateData.status === "Declined" && GlobalStyle.ReceiptDeclined,  migrateData.status === "Pending" && GlobalStyle.ReceiptPending]}>{migrateData.status}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
    </ScrollView>
    )
}
```

**dummy.js:**

[image]

Comment: What output are you getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add {"backgroundColor":"black"} in the view and change the color as you want

```
<View style={[GlobalStyle.ReceiptPendingContainer,{"backgroundColor":status === "Pending" ? "yellow": status === "Declined" ? "red" : "green" }]}>
    <Text style={[GlobalStyle.ReceiptAccept, migrateData.status === "Declined" && GlobalStyle.ReceiptDeclined,  migrateData.status === "Pending" && GlobalStyle.ReceiptPending]}>{migrateData.status}</Text>
 </View>
```

Comment: I would like to use 1 status pending container to change all the status container colour for declined page and also accept page, how would the code look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const getTextStyle = (status) => {
  switch(status){
    case "Declined":
      return GlobalStyle.ReceiptDeclined
    case "Pending":
      return GlobalStyle.ReceiptPending
    default:
      return {}
  }
}

return (
...
  <Text style={[GlobalStyle.ReceiptAccept, getTextStyle()]}>{migrateData.status}</Text>
...
)
```